# time estimated for download and upload file(in python)

Tags: python-2.7

i want a code for time estimated to down/up file and speed.i want to integrate this part at back end.

What would be the way to get the network speed and time estimation using Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get upload/download kbps speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866951/get-upload-download-kbps-speed)

Comment: but its not working in pycharm editor

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the throughput speed of the client Connection download/upload and divide it buy the File size that's the logic there are many plug ins to determine the speed 
put please don't wait for some one to spoon feed you the code 
you're a programmer after all

cheers..

Comment: i want a time estimation for down/up file..and i'm not a good programmer